# htaccess redirect weird url target.how to fix this?

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to set a redirect URL that has parameter using .htaccess
The code below works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /+news-search\?category=95
     RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.net/about/ad/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I input the following URL:
http://www.kow.work/doctor/news-search?category=95

I get this as a result:
http://www.example.net/about/ad/?/doctor/news-search

The expected result, however, is:
http://www.example.net/about/ad/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the query string using the [QSD](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd) flag. Try:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.net/about/ad/ [L,R=301,QSD]
```

or the old way, adding a `?`

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.test.net/about/ad/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: thank you very much,It work but there is another way to do like this ? if my apache version under 2.4